# AWS API Gateway returns TARGET_MODEL_HEADER_MISSING even though target model passed in header

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, api-gateway

I have a deployed endpoint for a Sagemaker MultiDataModel. I can call it succesfully from my local computer using boto3.
I've set up an API Gateway to this Sagemaker MultiDataModel and I am trying to retrieve predictions from the model using a https request. But I keep getting a TARGET_MODEL_HEADER_MISSING-error.

My https request looks like this:

```
import requests
headers = {'X-Amzn-SageMaker-Target-Model':'/jobtitles-exact'}
response = requests.request("POST"
, "https://XXXXXXXXXX.execute-api.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/v1/predicted-job-titles"
, headers = headers
, data = data
)
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_runtime_InvokeEndpoint.html) and the [source code](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/local/local_session.py)
it seems like I am providing the header with the target model correctly. But this is obvously not the case.

How am I supposed to provide the target model in the header with the https-request?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. API Gateway does not pass on headers to SageMaker unless explicitly told to.
To pass the header on:

1. Open your API's "Method Execution"
2. Go to "Method Requests"
3. Under "HTTP Request Headers" you should add the name of the header you want to add, e.g. like this:

[image: method request on header]

4. Go back to "Method execution"
5. Go to "Integration request"
6. Under HTTP "Headers" you add the header to be mapped and the mapping, e.g like this:
   [image]
   And voilà, the header is passed on.