# How to configure AWS API Gateway for NVIDIA Triton's Binary Data Protocol with AWS SageMaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sagemaker, tritonserver

I've deployed a model using the NVIDIA Triton Inference Server on AWS SageMaker and am attempting to expose it through a REST API using AWS API Gateway. This would make it accessible to clients.

Initially, I wrote code for directly invoking AWS SageMaker using the specific MIME type `application/vnd.sagemaker-triton.binary+json;json-header-size={NUMBER}` (as detailed in [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/deploy-models-frameworks-triton.html#deploy-models-frameworks-triton-payloads)). This MIME type in the Content-Type header, where `{NUMBER}` represents the number of bytes to be read as JSON followed by binary data, works flawlessly.

Following the [AWS blog instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/creating-a-machine-learning-powered-rest-api-with-amazon-api-gateway-mapping-templates-and-amazon-sagemaker/), I created an API and set it to proxy my responses to the SageMaker Runtime without modification. Additionally, I added `application/vnd.sagemaker-triton.binary+json` to the Binary Media Types to ensure it's proxied in binary form without alteration.

However, when I test the AWS Gateway endpoint, I encounter an error: `The error message (unexpected size for input 'np_tensor', expecting 4 additional bytes) suggests that the Triton server is not receiving the correct binary data size, possibly due to the way API Gateway is processing the request.`

It appears that AWS Gateway is not preserving the `Content-Type=application/vnd.sagemaker-triton.binary+json;json-header-size={NUMBER}` header. Omitting this header when directly accessing the SageMaker endpoint results in the same error.

Logs indicate that the header is initially present, but subsequent entries show only [truncated output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50365298/trace-full-request-response-bodies-in-aws-apigateway-not-truncated/52880294#52880294), which doesn't provide much help.

Here is the code snippet I used:

python client code

```py
import boto3
import botocore.session
from botocore.auth import SigV4Auth
from botocore.awsrequest import AWSRequest
import numpy as np
import json
import requests

aws_region = 'us-east-1'

# API Gateway URL
url = ""

# SageMaker Endpoint URL (commented out since we're using API Gateway)
# url = ""

# Sample dummy input data for testing
input_data = np.array([[-0.0024108887]]).astype('float32')

# Define the request body for the Triton server
json_request = {
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "np_tensor",
            "shape": list(input_data.shape),
            "datatype": "FP32",
            "parameters": {"binary_data_size": input_data.nbytes},
        },
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {"name": "transcription", "parameters": {"binary_data": True}},
    ],
}

# Convert the request to a JSON string and then to bytes
json_request_str = json.dumps(json_request)
request_body = json_request_str.encode() + input_data.tobytes()
header_length = len(json_request_str)

# # Not needed for AWS Gateway
# # AWS session and credentials setup
# session = boto3.Session()
# credentials = session.get_credentials()

# # AWS Request with SigV4 Authentication
# request = AWSRequest(method="POST", url=url, data=request_body)
# SigV4Auth(credentials, 'sagemaker', aws_region).add_auth(request)

# signed_headers = dict(request.headers)

# Prepare headers, including the custom Content-Type header
signed_headers = {}
signed_headers["Content-Type"] = "application/vnd.sagemaker-triton.binary+json;json-header-size={}".format(header_length)

# Send the request and print the response
response = requests.post(
    url, 
    headers=signed_headers,
    data=request_body
)

print(response.content.decode("utf8"))
```

My questions are:

1. How can I ensure that AWS Gateway preserves the custom Content-Type header when proxying requests to SageMaker?
2. Are there any additional configurations or settings in AWS Gateway that I might be missing to handle this type of request?
3. Has anyone successfully configured a similar setup with AWS Gateway and SageMaker using Triton's binary data extension?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68559729)! Amazon API Gateway does not pass on headers to SageMaker unless explicitly told to (which is a bit counterintuitive because it's not explicitly mentioned). To pass the header on:

1. Open your API's "Method Execution"
2. Go to "Method Requests"
3. Under "HTTP Request Headers" you should add the name of the header you want to add, e.g. like this:
   [image]
4. Go back to "Method execution"
5. Go to "Integration request"
6. Under "URL request headers parameters" you add the header to be mapped and the mapping, e.g like this:

   `Content-Type` -> `method.request.header.Content-Type`
   [image]
7. Click "Deploy"

---

P.S.

Don't forget to also add an "Accept" header in both your request and the gateway settings if your return type doesn't match the input type defined in "Content-Type". Otherwise e.g for AWS MMS server you will get something like:

```
Content type is not supported by this framework. 

Please implement input_fn to to deserialize the request data or an output_fn 

to serialize the response. For more information, see the SageMaker Python SDK README.
```